# Who are the two people that look like Baltar and 6 at the end of the series?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In the last episodes of BSG we see Baltar and 6 walking in our present days and observing.

Who are they? Why do they look exactly like the original two? And why do they seem to know the "real story" of humanity as opposed to anyone else?

Quotes from Daybreak Part 2

> *Virtual Six*: Commercialism, decadence, technology run amok. Remind you of anything?
>   *Virtual Baltar*: Take your pick. Kobol. Earth... the real Earth, before this one. Caprica before the fall.
>   *Virtual Six*: All of this has happened before.
>   *Virtual Baltar*: But the question remains, does all of this have to happen again?
>   *Virtual Six*: This time I bet no.
>   *Virtual Baltar*: [Stops] You know, I've never known you to play the optimist. Why the change of heart?
>   *Virtual Six*: Mathematics. Law of averages. Let a complex system repeat itself long enough and eventually something surprising might occur. **That, too, is in God's plan.** 
>   *Virtual Baltar*: [Serious] You know it doesn't like that name.
>   [Six gives Baltar a defiant look] Silly me. Silly, silly me.
>   [The two walk arm-in-arm off into the streets.]

Comment: All of your questions really require opinion based answers, as there's never been given any real, hardline answers to these questions.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks: "There's no answer because <reason>" is also an answer.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, so long as the question isn't really encouraging discussion, the general consensus was that [questions without explicit answers were not necessarily off-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed).

Comment: @MyCodeSucks There has been a "[Word of God](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod)" answer given to this.  [I've cited it in my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40248/1359)

Comment: I believe they were intended to be hallucinations but as the show neared its end they decided to try to make them more. But it didn't really work too well.

Comment: @Chickc Can you offer anything more than your own opinion on this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the series co-creator [Ron Moore](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/sciencenotfiction/2009/03/20/battlestar-galactica-watched-the-finale-still-got-questions-weve-got-answers/#.UiXjytLBNxA), they are the "Head Six" and "Head Baltar", agents of a higher power.  They know the "real story" of humanity (and Cylons) because they are eternal, and were around for the previous cycles:

> *In the last scene, are “Six” and “Baltar” angels or demons?*
>
> **Moore:** I think they’re both. We never try to name exactly what the “Head” characters are—we called them “Head Baltar” and “Head Six” all throughout the show, internally. We never really looked at them as angels or demons because they seemed to periodically say evil things and good things, they tended to save people and they tended to damn people. There was this sense that they worked in service of something else. You could say “a higher power” or you could say “another power,” [but] they were in service to something else that was guiding and helping, sometimes obstructing, and sometimes tempting the people on the show. The idea at the very end was that whatever they are in service to continues and is eternal and is always around. And they too are still around…and with all of us who are the children of Hera. They continue to walk among us and watch, and at some point they may or may not intercede at a key moment.

Answer (score 8):

They're angels. They were the two the at the real Baltar and Caprica-6 had been 'hallucinating' during the events of BSG. They're there to ensure that what has happened before will happen again

Quotes from Daybreak Part 2

> Virtual Six: Commercialism, decadence, technology run amok. Remind you of anything?
>   Virtual Baltar: Take your pick. Kobol. Earth...the real Earth, before this one. Caprica before the fall.
>   Virtual Six: All of this has happened before.
>   Virtual Baltar: But the question remains, does all of this have to happen again?
>   Virtual Six: This time I bet no.
>   Virtual Baltar: [Stops] You know, I've never known you to play the optimist. Why the change of heart?
>   Virtual Six: Mathematics. Law of averages. Let a complex system repeat itself long enough and eventually something surprising might occur. **That, too, is in God's plan.** 
>   Virtual Baltar: [Serious] You know it doesn't like that name.[Six gives Baltar a defiant look] Silly me. Silly, silly me. [The two walk arm-in-arm off into the streets.]

Comment: any reference for this?

Comment: Watch the finale again.

Comment: "Angel" is a strong term without any real backing.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of BSG as a sort of Greek/Homeric saga, then the virtual 6 and virtual Baltar may be seen as representing the role similar to that of the chorus in the Greek theater. In the Greek tradition, the chorus would comment on the action in the play, and occasionally would take an active role as a character. The virtual characters in BSG may be considered the equivalent of an omniscient narrator/chorus.
But also ...
In the Greek context, the gods were real and took active roles. In BSG "the one true god" uses the virtual 6 to interact with Baltar -- and we may presume the virtual Baltar also has been interacting with Caprica 6 and guiding her actions in the same way. So we may consider the virtual 6 and Baltar to be avatars of the one true god, who also sometimes stand apart and comment like a Greek chorus might.
Personally I prefer this explanation to the one where they're considered angels or demigods directing actions.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend taking the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour). Also, this answer could be improved by quotes by any show creators backing your interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real answer that I've ever been able to find as to "who" or "what" they are. Same as with Starbuck. There's just no answer to the question. It's one of the tropes of "the answer is whatever you want it to be".

As for why do they look like 6 and Baltar, they took the form so that they could appear to their respective persons in order to manipulate events. Only 6 and Baltar could see them, and thus they appeared to be hallucinations to the two of them.

They appeared to know the real story of humanity because they appear to have been around for quite a long time. It's in my opinion that they were sent to prevent events from happening again, and to begin a new civilization, of which Cylon and Humans coexist.

Comment: So those two are the one we see in Baltar and 6 "mind" during the all show?

Comment: Yes, the ones you see at the end walking the "modern day" streets, are the same ones who appeared to 6 and Baltar as "hallucinations".

Comment: Or, their appearance is what they actually look like: 6 and Baltar. God-doesn't-like-that-name (GDLTN) has a sense of humor, and made real 6 and real Baltar look like two of his angels, so they didn't have to alter their appearance. Or, the fact that two pivotal characters look exactly like two of GDLTN's angels means they are died through fate to each other. Take your pick.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the answer is in this answer: "You know it doesn't like that name".

Humanity and c(y)lon(e)s are slaves in a material world where the owner is "the ruler of this world" (satan), so "what has happened before will happen again" in this "world": end of "battlestar galactica".

The two entities are demons able to manipulate humans by the human weaknesses appearing in a desirable and persuasive form so to realize this plan: (obviously the director and story writers make this situation ambiguous to avoid to unveil the truth).

The ending dialogue between the two entities appears useless if not unveil the aforementioned concept and the sentence "You know it doesn't like that name" unveils that humans are puppets in a theater of the "ruler of this world" in order to repeat  its show (Hera the progenitor unveils that the new Earth is the old Earth before where all humans originates from human cylons (Hera); human cylons are human clones (the five ones) or human copies from laboratory (the 8 ones "sons" of the five ones) So the process begins again until the end: the place where D'Anna preferred to stay and where Kara saw her fighter and her dead body.

Comment: Can you provide sources from the novels?