# Was Gaius Baltar a Cylon?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

I thought Baltar was a Cylon because he would communicate with 6 through subspace,
but what Baltar and 6 see in their head is not each other communicating through subspace but they are "Head 6" and "Head baltar" as proven by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/who-are-the-two-people-that-look-like-baltar-and-6-at-the-end-of-the-series?noredirect=1#comment76493_40243).

So now I don't know. Is the "normal" Baltar a Cylon or not?

Comment: Seems to me that the question you link to answers this exhaustively and being agents of a higher power, they cannot be cylons...

Comment: I'm talking about the "Normal" Baltar. "Head Baltar" is something else

Comment: Why would you assume that Baltar is a Cylon just because he could communicate with an agent of a higher power? Head Six and Head Baltar were trying to guide both sides of the conflict.

Comment: I assumed that before I knoew he was communicating with higher powers. I thought it was Cylon subspace communication... or crazyness :)

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark: It's neither. A plot hole is what it is.

Comment: @Dima: A plot hole is when the writers make a glaring mistake that is picked up by the viewers. Not making something obvious to a viewer is NOT a plot hole. Something that is explained within the context of the SHOW (Head Six and Head Baltar are space angels, and are not bound by normal rules) is not a plot hole, either.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Gaius Baltar cannot be a Cylon. We know exactly how many models of Cylon there are: 13. And they're all accounted for.

> The eight we see most often: respectively John, Leoben, D'Anna, Simon, Aaron Doral, Number Six (i.e. Shelley and Gina), Daniel (who was boxed before the events of BSG), and Boomer/Athena; the "Final Five", survivors of the original Earth: Anders, Foster, Ellen and Saul Tigh, and Tyrol.

Aside: The note that Adama gets at the end of the miniseries says there are *twelve* models, but that's because it doesn't include Daniel, who is for all intents and purposes no longer a model of Cylon. We never see Daniel, but after

> Ellen Tigh

becomes aware of her Cylon-ness, she remembers him. And at that point she would have recognized Gaius as being a Number Seven if that were the case.

Comment: Was the appearance of the Daniel/Number 7 model ever revealed?

Comment: No, but one of the final five remembered him (I've put her name in a spoiler tag in my answer), and she would have realized if Baltar was a Number Seven.

Comment: Right, everything pointed to Baltar not being a Cylon - and I seem to recall all the Daniels being effectively destroyed. My point was more that we, as viewers, never learn if there was really a stray seven walking around somewhere since his appearance was never revealed.

Comment: I'd dispute the finality of this answer on the basis that theres more than one type of Cylon....  We have the skinjobs introduced from the outset of the miniseries, leading to the 8 original humanoid cylons and the "final five" who are descended from the Cylons from Kobol, recreated resurrection and created the other eight models for the Colonies Cylons.  Theres nothing in canon to prevent other Kobol-descended Cylons from having travelled independently to the Colonies (and admittedly nothing in canon to support this either), and they wouldnt be known to any of the other Cylons...

Answer (score 2):

In Season 3 episode 13, Baltar attempted suicide in jail and was brought back by a medic. A cylon cannot be brought back to life. It would have downloaded into a new body.

Case closed.

Comment: maybe he saw the white light of the downloading machine but the defibrillator shut down the wi-fi and terminated the download. :)

Answer (score -3):

This is a tough one. At the end of the series, you see Baltar walking away arm in arm with the original Cylon we see him with in the beginning. Is it a flashback or a sign of things to come. Consequently, is the second series a standalone or, based on the conclusion of the second series, a continuation of the first, just a loop in time with names remaining the same, just the being holding that name to be different

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This commentary doesn't give an answer the question one way or the other.  Please only post answers; when you've earned some reputation you'll be able to leave comments.