# What did Gaius Baltar mean when he said "silly me" at the very end of Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

At the very end of Battlestar Galactica, Gaius Baltar says "you know it doesn't like that name" in reference to the label 'God'.... But then he smirks and goes on to say "silly me".

What was that part about?

Comment: Note that this particular character is not usually referred to as Gaius Baltar (which is reserved for the actual Baltar), but is instead called either “Virtual Baltar” or “Head Baltar”.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for this quote?

Answer (score 5):

A previous answer to this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/who-are-the-two-people-that-look-like-baltar-and-6-at-the-end-of-the-series?rq=1) provides this information

> In the last scene, are “Six” and “Baltar” angels or demons?

> Moore: I think they’re both. We never try to name exactly what the “Head” characters are—we called them “Head Baltar” and “Head Six” all throughout the show, internally. We never really looked at them as angels or demons because they seemed to periodically say evil things and good things, they tended to save people and they tended to damn people.

With this context, "Silly me" seems to be a self-deprecating acknowledgement that Head Baltar has given Head Six information that Head Six is already well aware of, since they are both well acquainted with the God who does not like that name.